# Update the inserted record in ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project I am inserting an employee and as my employee is inserted my save button HTML turns to update and on the back-end I am using the same insert function for updating the employee which I just inserted, my insert functionality is working perfectly but as I attempt to update the same record it inserts a new record in database instead of updating the data against the inserted ID, how do I update the existing or currently inserted user against their respective IDs.

I do not know why my update is not working and why I am not able to update right after inserting the user, every time I try to update the user I end up inserting the user again, and how should I restrict my application from inserting similar data again and again, the insert and update button are the same, as I mentioned above that on inserting the user I am changing the inner HTML of my button from save to update and using that same button to update

Here is my complete code, please let me know If I am making any mistakes at any part of my code, all the help I get from you guys is highly appreciated

My stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsEmpOfficialDetails] 
    (@EmpID int = NULL,
     @UserName varchar(500) = NULL,
     @pass varchar(500) = NULL,
     @OfficialEmailAddress varchar(500) = NULL,
     @Department varchar(500) = NULL,
     @RoleID int = NULL,
     @Role varchar(500) = NULL,
     @IsAdmin bit = NULL,
     @Designation varchar(500) = NULL,
     @ReportToID int = NULL,
     @ReportTo varchar(500) = NULL,
     @JoiningDate datetime = NULL,
     @IsPermanent bit = NULL,
     @DateofPermanancy datetime = NULL,
     @IsActive bit = NULL,
     @HiredbyReference bit = NULL,
     @HiredbyReferenceName varchar(500) = NULL,
     @BasicSalary int = NULL,
     @CurrentPicURL nvarchar(max) = NULL
     -- @CreatedBy int,                                 
     -- @CreatedOn datetime,                
     -- @UpdatedOn datetime,                                
     -- @UpdatedBy int                                  
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee 
               WHERE UserName = @UserName
                 AND pass = @pass
                 AND OfficialEmailAddress = @OfficialEmailAddress
                 AND Department = @Department
                 AND RoleID = @RoleID
                 AND Role = @Role
                 AND IsAdmin = @IsAdmin
                 AND Designation = @Designation
                 AND ReportToID = @ReportToID
                 AND ReportTo = @ReportTo
                 AND JoiningDate = @JoiningDate
                 AND IsPermanent = @IsPermanent
                 AND DateofPermanancy = @DateofPermanancy
                 AND IsActive = @IsActive
                 AND HiredbyReference = @HiredbyReference
                 AND HiredbyReferenceName = HiredbyReferenceName
                 AND BasicSalary = @BasicSalary
                 AND CurrentPicURL = @CurrentPicURL)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Employee
        SET UserName = @UserName,
            pass = @pass,
            OfficialEmailAddress = @OfficialEmailAddress,
            Department = @Department,
            RoleID = @RoleID,
            Role = @Role,
            IsAdmin = @IsAdmin,
            Designation = @Designation,
            ReportToID = @ReportToID,
            ReportTo = @ReportTo,
            JoiningDate = @JoiningDate,
            IsPermanent = @IsPermanent,
            DateofPermanancy = @DateofPermanancy,
            IsActive = @IsActive,
            HiredbyReference = @HiredbyReference,
            HiredbyReferenceName = HiredbyReferenceName,
            BasicSalary = @BasicSalary,
            CurrentPicURL = @CurrentPicURL
        WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Employee(UserName, pass,
OfficialEmailAddress,Department,
RoleID, Role, IsAdmin, Designation,
ReportToID, ReportTo, JoiningDate,
IsPermanent, DateofPermanancy, IsActive,
HiredbyReference, HiredbyReferenceName,
BasicSalary, CurrentPicURL)
        VALUES (@UserName, @pass, @OfficialEmailAddress, @Department,
                @RoleID, @Role, @IsAdmin, @Designation,
                @ReportToID, @ReportTo, @JoiningDate,
                @IsPermanent, @DateofPermanancy, @IsActive,
                @HiredbyReference, @HiredbyReferenceName,
                @BasicSalary, @CurrentPicURL)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
END
```

In my HTML on top of my input fields I am storing the currently inserted user ID in a hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden" class="HiddenID" />
```

I do not know how to use this hidden field ID for updating the User right after inserting, because as I mentioned my insert and update functions both lies on same button

My ajax code:

```
$('.empOfficialDetails').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var data = new Object();
    data.UserName = $('#username').val();
    data.UPassword = $('#userpass').val();
    data.OfficialEmailAddress = $('#officialemail').val();
    data.Departments = $('#departments :selected').text();
    data.Designation = $('#designation :selected').text();
    data.RoleID = $('#role').val();
    data.Role = $('#role :selected').text();
    data.ReportToID = $('#reportToID').val();
    data.ReportTo = $('#reportTo :selected').text();
    data.JoiningDate = $('#joindate').val();
    data.IsAdmin = $('#isAdmin :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsActive = $('#isActive :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsPermanent = $('#isPermanent :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.DateofPermanancy = $('#permanantdate').val();
    data.HiredbyReference = $('#hiredbyRef :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.HiredbyReferenceName = $('#refePersonName').val();
    data.BasicSalary = $('#basicSalary').val();
    data.CurrentPicURL = $('.picture').val();
    //data.CurrentPicURL = $('.picture')[0].files;

    if (data.UserName && data.UPassword && data.OfficialEmailAddress && data.Departments && data.Designation && data.Role && data.IsAdmin && data.IsPermanent) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmpOfficialDetails',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var ID = parseInt(data);
                if (ID > 0) {
                    //var id = data;
                    $(".HiddenID").val(data);
                    //var id = $(".HiddenID").val();
                    $('#official').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#official').html("Employees Official details added successfully...!");
                    $('#official').fadeOut(25000);
                    $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();

                    $('.empOfficialDetails').html("Update &nbsp; <i class='fa fa-angle-right rotate-icon'></i>");
                }
                else {
                    $('#official').find("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger").remove("alert alert-success");
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert("There was an error while submitting employee data");
                alert('Error' + ex.responseXML);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseText);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseJSON);
                alert('Error' + ex.readyState);
                alert('Error' + ex.statusText);
            }
        });
        
    }
    return false;

});
```

my controller code:

```
public int Emp_OfficialDetails(Employee emp)
    {
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AmanraHRMS"].ConnectionString);
        var con = DB.getDatabaseConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsEmpOfficialDetails", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        #region Employee Official Details Insert Code block

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", emp.UserName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", emp.UPassword);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficialEmailAddress", emp.OfficialEmailAddress);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", emp.Departments);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", emp.Role);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAdmin", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsAdmin));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", emp.Designation);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportToID", emp.ReportToID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportTo", emp.ReportTo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JoiningDate", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.JoiningDate));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsPermanent", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsPermanent));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofPermanancy", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DateofPermanancy));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsActive));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HiredbyReference", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.HiredbyReference));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HiredbyReferenceName", emp.HiredbyReferenceName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BasicSalary", emp.BasicSalary);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentPicURL", emp.CurrentPicURL);

        #endregion
        //var file = emp.CurrentPicURL;

        //EmployeeImage(file);

        var ID = com.ExecuteScalar();
        com.Clone();
        return Convert.ToInt32(ID);
    }

    //Ajax call hit this method from AddEmployee page
    [Route("api/Employee/EmpOfficialDetails")]
    [HttpPost]
    public int? EmpOfficialDetails(Employee emp)
    {
        IHttpActionResult ret;
        try
        {
            var id = Emp_OfficialDetails(emp);
            return id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ret = InternalServerError(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: updated the question and renamed the stored procedure both in sql and in my controller where I am calling my stored procedure as you highlighted sir @marc_s

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Many of these comments have been previously made - are you learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for ="EmpID"  id="empId" class="HiddenID" value="@Model.EmpID />
```

fix your stored procedure. for exist would be enough EmpID, too many parameters can give the wrong result

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee 
               WHERE EmpID = @EmpID)
 BEGIN
        UPDATE Employee
        SET UserName = @UserName,
         .....
```

and the most important add EmpId to ajax

```
  var data = new Object();
    data.EmpID = $('#empId').val();
```

and action command

```
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", emp.EmpID);
```

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your answer I really appreciate it, your answer solved about almost half of my problem but now there is an other big problem then this I will post the code with all the details, this question was for updating the inserted user on the spot, but my next issue is the super edit a function where I am retrieving users complete information and updating it section by section

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAousajaAli What is your question?

Comment: Sir @serge I have posted the question, i guess my question will be on the feed right now